# log4j initialization issue

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

First of all I need to say that I'm newbie in Java and Java-related technologies.
Recently I got a big project in Java. It has client and server sides. When I'm trying to call client-side application, it gives me following warning:

```
`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.security.SecurityAssociation).  
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`
```

Ok, it seems like log4j can't find its properties file. I didn't find any, so I wrote a new one:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.file=server.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n`
```

And now I have no idea where I have to put it. Documentation says, that it has to be in classpath - so I tried to put it into `/src/` subdirectory of `client`, `web` and `webinfo` folders. I also tried the root folder of project - but it keeps giving me warnings.
Does anybody know good manual on "How to find a place to put log4j.properties file" topic? Or maybe I have to write somewhere in jboss configuration files that I'm using the following `log4j.properties` file?

Comment: could you provide your project structure! after that maybe I can say something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `log4j properties` in different ways,

- As you said, it has to be in `classpath`, For any web application default classpath would be `WEB-INF/classes`, You can place `log4j.properties` file there. If it is not web application, try to find where all your classes resides, usually inside `bin` folder.
- Other way is you can configure it via `VM args`

`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/testing/mylog4j.properties`

Comment: Ok, finally I found `WEB-INF` directory in one of the numerous folders of our project, added sub-directory `classes` to it, and put the file log4j.properties in the `classes`. And it works!
Thank you for your help, it saved me a lot of headache.:)

Answer (score 0):

Keep a shared library(a folder with any name) and append it to your server's classpath.You can place any external jars ,log4j configurations etc.. in this folder.Since it is appended to ur server's classpath it will be loaded.

Note:If you make any changes to this folder you will need a server restart for the changes to take effect.

Hope this helps !!!☺